# Passing variables to process

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In Spring Batch I have a custom ItemProcessor. I want to pass information from the afterStep to the process method. Here's the code

```
@Component
public class Clf010Processor implements ItemProcessor<Clf010Item, Clf010Item> {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    BatchProgram batch = new BatchProgram();

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExecutionContext je = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        // Pass the counts up to the execution context.
        je.putLong("writeCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        je.putLong("clfCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public Clf010Item process(Clf010Item item) throws Exception {
        batch.print("writeCount = ", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        return item;
    }

}
```

I want to access writeCount and clfCount from after step in process. Like:

```
@Override
public Clf010Item process(Clf010Item item) throws Exception {
    batch.print("writecount = ", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    return item;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Mahmoud Ben Hassine's answer, here is my code:

```
@Component
public class Clf010Processor implements ItemProcessor<Clf010Item, Clf010Item> {

    BatchProgram batch = new BatchProgram();

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExecutionContext je = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        // Pass the counts up to the execution context.
        je.putLong("writeCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        je.putLong("clfCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        je.putLong("readCount", stepExecution.getReadCount());
        // Log the program results
        batch.print("");
        batch.print("**********************************************************");
        batch.print("INPUT RECORDS READ =  " + stepExecution.getReadCount());
        batch.print("**********************************************************");
        batch.print("");
        batch.print("**********************************************************");
        batch.print("OUTPUT RECORDS WRITTEN =  " + stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        batch.print("**********************************************************");
        batch.print("");
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

    @Override
    public Clf010Item process(Clf010Item item) throws Exception {
        return item;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think it is a [common pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) to hand over infos via the `StepExecution`. In that case the `StepExecution` is held as a member variable in of the `ItemProcessor` and can be set via the `beforeStep` method. E.g:

```
public class Clf010Processor implements ItemProcessor<Clf010Item, Clf010Item> {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExecutionContext je = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        // Pass the counts up to the execution context.
        je.putLong("writeCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        je.putLong("clfCount", stepExecution.getWriteCount());
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public Clf010Item process(Clf010Item item) throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        long writeCount = jobContext.getLong("writeCount");
        batch.print("writecount = ", writeCount);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, "writeCount = " goes to my console where I want it, but there is no value being printed by `stepExecution.getWriteCount();`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated my answer to get the writeCount via `jobContext.getLong("writeCount")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I'll choose a correct answer once I get things working.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass information from the afterStep to the process method

The method annotated with `AfterStep` will be executed **after** the entire step is finished (including reading, processing and writing), but the `process` method is executed **while** the step is running. So the information you are requesting in `process` (the `writeCount`) is not available yet at that moment.

Comment: So in this case, if I wanted to log out the total writeCount, I would be wanting to perform this in the `AfterStep` , right?

Comment: Exact. The write count would be available at that point in time (ie, when the step is finished).

Comment: Thank you. I'm now able to log my program results.